# help me to prove this condition number!

Tags: numerical-methods

I want to prove this, but I have some questions.
If we define $f_n$ like this.
$$
f_n = (-1)^n \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(\frac{e^{-x}}{x}) \quad n =0,1,2,... \quad f_0 = \frac{e^{-x}}{x}
$$
Prove this.
$$
(cond f_n)(f_0) =\frac{1}{|e_n(x)|} , \quad e_n(x) =1 + x + x^2/2! + ... + x^n/n!
$$
I know that I should compute $f_n$ with Leibniz formula and it will be 
$$
f_n = n!\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\frac{e^{-x}}{(n-k)!x^{k+1}}
$$
I don't know whether I can use this formula $(cond f)(x) = |\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}|$ or I should use the definition of condition number. Can any one help me .I have problem because it wants $(cond f_n)(f_0)$